# mvn exec:java -DGetSwaggerDoc throws java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WHITESPACE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I tried generating `swagger.json` by executing `mvn exec:java -DGetSwaggerDoc` from terminal, following the "Generating the OpenAPI configuration spec" section of https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/quickstart-frameworks-java. This is what I get:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building web 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) @ web ---
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WHITESPACE
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXml.toNullIfEmptyOrWhitespace(AppEngineWebXml.java:994)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXml.setInstanceClass(AppEngineWebXml.java:241)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.processInstanceClassNode(AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.java:225)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.processSecondLevelNode(AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.java:144)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.processXml(AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.java:68)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.processXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:132)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:76)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AppEngineUtil.getAppProperty(AppEngineUtil.java:129)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AppEngineUtil.getApplicationId(AppEngineUtil.java:52)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AppEngineUtil.getApplicationDefaultHostname(AppEngineUtil.java:91)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsToolAction.getHostname(EndpointsToolAction.java:226)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GetSwaggerDocAction.execute(GetSwaggerDocAction.java:78)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool.execute(EndpointsTool.java:83)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool.main(EndpointsTool.java:115)
    ... 6 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.868 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-02T15:17:06+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project web: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: WHITESPACE -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

This is my `appengine-web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">

    <application>bla</application>
    <module>default</module>
    <version>r1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <instance-class>F1</instance-class>

    <env-variables>
        <env-var name="ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME" value="bla.appspot.com"/>
    </env-variables>

    <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file"
                  value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
        <property name="gcm.api.key" value="BLA"/>
        <property name="ae-cloudsql.cloudsql-database-url"
                  value="jdbc:google:mysql://bla:us-central1:db0/bla?user=root&amp;password=bla&amp;useUnicode=true"/>
        <property name="ae-cloudsql.local-database-url"
                  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bla?user=root&amp;password=&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;useSSL=false"/>
    </system-properties>

    <automatic-scaling>
        <min-idle-instances>1</min-idle-instances>
        <max-idle-instances>3</max-idle-instances>
        <min-pending-latency>250ms</min-pending-latency>
        <max-pending-latency>1000ms</max-pending-latency>
    </automatic-scaling>

</appengine-web-app>
```

I'm using Endpoints Framework 2.0.0-beta.9. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you try editing `pom.xml` and changing `<version>1.9.30</version>` to `<version>${appengine.sdk.version}</version>`?

Comment: There is an open issue here: https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java/issues/24